# In DB2 Display a table's definition

Tags: db2

Hello everybody I am learning DB2 and would like to know how to 
see a table's characteristics after I create one.

Similar to the EXPLAIN TABLE command in MySQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to `DESCRIBE TABLE`, you can use the command below

```
DESCRIBE INDEXES FOR TABLE *tablename* SHOW DETAIL
```

to get information about the table's indexes.

The most comprehensive detail about a table on Db2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows can be obtained from the db2look utility, which you can run from a remote client or directly on the Db2 server as a local user. The tool produces the DDL and other information necessary to mimic tables and their statistical data. The docs for db2look in Db2 11.5 are [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html).

The following `db2look` command will connect to the SALESDB database and obtain the DDL statements necessary to recreate the ORDERS table

```
db2look -d SALESDB -e -t ORDERS
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but this will do the job.

```
SELECT colname, typename, length, scale, default, nulls
  FROM syscat.columns
 WHERE tabname = '<table name>'
   AND tabschema = '<schema name>'
 ORDER BY colno
```

Comment: Hi Todd.. Do u know any query which will give the-- ddl statement for the table/index alone? TIA

Comment: To which versions of DB2 does this apply ? I'm working with 7.2 and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Apparently for older versions, you need to use sysibm rather than syscat.

Comment: Note that the `tabname` and `tabschema` values are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

db2look -d <db_name> -e -z <schema_name> -t <table_name> -i <user_name> -w <password> > <file_name>.sql

For more information, please refer below:

```
    db2look [-h]

    -d: Database Name: This must be specified

    -e: Extract DDL file needed to duplicate database
   -xs: Export XSR objects and generate a script containing DDL statements
 -xdir: Path name: the directory in which XSR objects will be placed
    -u: Creator ID: If -u and -a are both not specified then $USER will be used
    -z: Schema name: If -z and -a are both specified then -z will be ignored
    -t: Generate statistics for the specified tables
   -tw: Generate DDLs for tables whose names match the pattern criteria (wildcard characters) of the table name
   -ap: Generate AUDIT USING Statements
  -wlm: Generate WLM specific DDL Statements
  -mod: Generate DDL statements for Module
  -cor: Generate DDL with CREATE OR REPLACE clause
 -wrap: Generates obfuscated versions of DDL statements
    -h: More detailed help message
    -o: Redirects the output to the given file name
    -a: Generate statistics for all creators
    -m: Run the db2look utility in mimic mode
        -c: Do not generate COMMIT statements for mimic
        -r: Do not generate RUNSTATS statements for mimic
    -l: Generate Database Layout: Database partition groups, Bufferpools and Tablespaces
    -x: Generate Authorization statements DDL excluding the original definer of the object
   -xd: Generate Authorization statements DDL including the original definer of the object
    -f: Extract configuration parameters and environment variables
   -td: Specifies x to be statement delimiter (default is semicolon(;))
    -i: User ID to log on to the server where the database resides
    -w: Password to log on to the server where the database resides
```

Comment: There is many options to generate ddl of particular db2 table. Please choose the necessary detail for your search.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax for Describe table

```
db2 describe table <tablename>
```

or
For all table details

```
select * from syscat.tables
```

or
For all table details

```
 select * from sysibm.tables
```

Answer (score 4):

All that metadata is held in the DB2 catalog tables in the `SYSIBM` 'schema'. It varies for the DB2/z mainframe product and the DB2/LUW distributed product but they're coming closer and closer with each release.

IBM conveniently place all their manuals up on the `publib` site for the world to access. My area of expertise, DB2/z, has the pages you want [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_catalogtablesintro.htm).

There are a number of tables there that you'll need to reference:

```
SYSTABLES        for table information.
SYSINDEXES    \
SYSINDEXPART   + for index information.
SYSKEYS       /
SYSCOLUMNS       for column information.
```

The list of all information centers is [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/publications/us/library/index.shtml) which should point you to the DB2/LUW version if that's your area of interest.

Comment: Hi Pax, Can you frame the above answer in query, then it will be much helpfull to me.. TIA

Comment: I am copying all my tables to another tablespace by 
exporting tables and importing with create option with 
diffrent names. I have noticed primary index are 
created. However, my secondary indexes are not 
creating because the same index name already existed. 
Now I am trying to get ddl statements for those 
indexes. Is any body give me a db2look statements to 
get only the index 
ddl statements for this database. 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the table in DB2 Control Center and chose Generate DDL...  That will give you everything you need and more.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this query to describe a table in winsql

```
select NAME,TBNAME,COLTYPE,LENGTH,REMARKS,SCALE from sysibm.syscolumns
where tbcreator = 'Schema_name' and tbname='Table_name' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM TABLE_name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below command to see the complete characteristics of DB

```
db2look -d <DB NAme>-u walid -e -o
```

you can use the below command to see the complete characteristics of Schema

```
 db2look -d <DB NAme> -u walid -z <Schema Name> -e -o
```

you can use the below command to see the complete characteristics of table

```
db2look -d <DB NAme> -u walid -z <Schema Name> -t <Table Name>-e -o
```

you can also visit the below link for more details.
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002051.htm

Comment: To check the indexes on table use the below command, describe indexes for table schemeaName.TableName

Comment: To check the details of indexes on table use the below command, describe indexes for table schemeaName.TableName show detail

Answer (score 0):

Describe table syntax

```
describe table schemaName.TableName
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh.. do u know any query which will give the-- ddl statement for the table/index alone? TIA

Answer (score 0):

DB2 Version 11.0

```
Columns:
--------
SELECT NAME,COLTYPE,NULLS,LENGTH,SCALE,DEFAULT,DEFAULTVALUE FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS where TBcreator ='ME' and TBNAME ='MY_TABLE' ORDER BY COLNO;

Indexes:
--------
SELECT P.SPACE, K.IXNAME, I.UNIQUERULE, I.CLUSTERING, K.COLNAME, K.COLNO, K.ORDERING
FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES I
    JOIN SYSIBM.SYSINDEXPART P
        ON I.NAME = P.IXNAME
        AND I.CREATOR = P.IXCREATOR
    JOIN SYSIBM.SYSKEYS K
        ON P.IXNAME = K.IXNAME
        AND P.IXCREATOR = K.IXCREATOR
WHERE I.TBcreator ='ME' and I.TBNAME ='MY_TABLE'
ORDER BY K.IXNAME, K.COLSEQ;
```